# Deploying django on mod_wsgi

Tags: apache-2.4, python, django, mod-wsgi

The problem:
I get 404 error when trying to reach localhost:80.

```
[root@alarmpi public_html]# tail -n 1 /var/log/httpd/error_log 
[Sat Jun 04 23:09:50.235251 2016] [wsgi:error] [pid 2323:tid 1973417008] [client ::1:45230] Target WSGI script not found or unable to stat: /home/alarm/public_html/hamstergangster.eu/hamstergangster/hamstergangster/apache/wsgy.py
```

The system:
Using fresh install of Arch Arm on Raspberry Pi 2.

```
[root@alarmpi alarm]# apachectl -V
AH00558: httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using fe80::ba27:ebff:fed4:595a. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
Server version: Apache/2.4.20 (Unix)
Server built:   Apr 18 2016 12:41:21
Server's Module Magic Number: 20120211:57
Server loaded:  APR 1.5.2, APR-UTIL 1.5.4
Compiled using: APR 1.5.2, APR-UTIL 1.5.4
Architecture:   32-bit
Server MPM:     event
  threaded:     yes (fixed thread count)
    forked:     yes (variable process count)
Server compiled with....
 -D APR_HAS_SENDFILE
 -D APR_HAS_MMAP
 -D APR_HAVE_IPV6 (IPv4-mapped addresses enabled)
 -D APR_USE_SYSVSEM_SERIALIZE
 -D APR_USE_PTHREAD_SERIALIZE
 -D SINGLE_LISTEN_UNSERIALIZED_ACCEPT
 -D APR_HAS_OTHER_CHILD
 -D AP_HAVE_RELIABLE_PIPED_LOGS
 -D DYNAMIC_MODULE_LIMIT=256
 -D HTTPD_ROOT="/etc/httpd"
 -D SUEXEC_BIN="/usr/bin/suexec"
 -D DEFAULT_PIDLOG="/run/httpd/httpd.pid"
 -D DEFAULT_SCOREBOARD="logs/apache_runtime_status"
 -D DEFAULT_ERRORLOG="logs/error_log"
 -D AP_TYPES_CONFIG_FILE="conf/mime.types"
 -D SERVER_CONFIG_FILE="conf/httpd.conf"
[root@alarmpi hamstergangster.eu]#apachectl -k restart       
[root@alarmpi hamstergangster.eu]# tail -n 5 /var/log/httpd/error_log 
[Sat Jun 04 22:19:50.348445 2016] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 327:tid 1995890688] AH00494: SIGHUP received.  Attempting to restart
AH00558: httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using fe80::ba27:ebff:fed4:595a. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
[Sat Jun 04 22:19:50.403560 2016] [lbmethod_heartbeat:notice] [pid 327:tid 1995890688] AH02282: No slotmem from mod_heartmonitor
[Sat Jun 04 22:19:50.409304 2016] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 327:tid 1995890688] AH00489: Apache/2.4.20 (Unix) mod_wsgi/4.4.22 Python/3.5.1 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sat Jun 04 22:19:50.409539 2016] [core:notice] [pid 327:tid 1995890688] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/bin/httpd'
[root@alarmpi hamstergangster.eu]# source venv/bin/activate
(venv) [root@alarmpi hamstergangster.eu]# python       
Python 3.5.1 (default, Mar  6 2016, 10:14:04) 
[GCC 5.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import django
>>> django.VERSION
(1, 9, 6, 'final', 0)
```

Configuration:
`/home` and `/home/alarm` have 777 permissions `/home/alarm/public_htmml` and **everything** inside also have 777 permissions; not a permission issue.

TL;DR standard new Django project in virtual environment.
Precise commands:

```
mkdir -p /home/alarm/public_html/hamstergangster.eu
cd /home/alarm/public_html/hamstergangster.eu
virtualenv venv -p python3.5
source venv/bin/activate
pip install django
django-admin startproject hamstergangster
cd hamstergangster
django-admin startapp helloapp #configuring helloapp to take care of / and return HttpResponse("Hello World")
./manage.py makemigrations
./manage.py migrate
```

Works fine on dev server.

```
/home/alarm/public_html/hamstergangster.eu/hamstergangster/hamstergangster/apache
__init__.py  override.py  wsgi.py
```

I don't think there's a need for wsgi.py contents, as it's not loaded at all.

```
/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf
#Lines lines lines...
LoadModule wsgi_module modules/mod_wsgi.so
#Lines lines lines...
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName localhost
        WSGIScriptAlias / /home/alarm/public_html/hamstergangster.eu/hamstergangster/hamstergangster/wsgy.py

        <Directory /home/alarm/public_html/hamstergangster.eu/hamstergangster/hamstergangster/apache/">
        <Files wsgi.py>
        Require all granted
        </Files>
        </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

Everything inside one big httpd.conf (as default)

Tutorials I tried following:
http://pastebin.com/NTSC1Kj3
I got the idea how to use virtualenvs from django's official documentation

So, what hacks do I do to get my beloved "Hello World" appear in my Lynx screen?
Note that I'm a developer, not a sysadmin, and I'm overlooking something fairly obvious.
I have checked for `/home/alarm/public_html/hamstergangster.eu/hamstergangster/hamstergangster/apache/wsgi.py` existence and for permissions on every part of the path (by setting them to 777).

Answer (score 0):

If the error says file cannot be found

```
Target WSGI script not found or unable to stat: /home/alarm/public_html/hamstergangster.eu/hamstergangster/hamstergangster/apache/wsgy.py
```

, try `cat`ing it

```
cat /home/alarm/public_html/hamstergangster.eu/hamstergangster/hamstergangster/apache/wsgy.py
```

That helped me to notice the grammar mistake I have made - it's `wsgi.py`, not `wsgy.py`. I haven't noticed that when `cd`ing into the directory :D